# Interpolate Triangular Grid

Tags: matlab, interpolation

I have a triangular grid as used in [`trimesh`](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/trimesh.html) where the `z`-coordinate is a (smooth) function of `x,y`. The triangulation is given by some index Matrix `t`, so I could display this piecewise linear approximation given by the grid as

```
 trimesh(t,x,y,f(x,y))
```

Now I'd like to evaluate this apprixmation between the grid points i.e. in some general `x0,y0`. I am aware of `griddata`, but this function creates an new triangulation. I'd like to use the given triangulation `t`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a triangulation created by `delaunay` :

```
tri = delaunay (X, Y);
```

and coordinates of a point to be interpolated as `xi, yi`.

Use `tsearch`* or `pointLocation` to find the triangle that contains the point:

```
idx = tsearch (X, Y, tri, xi, yi);
```

Extract indices of vertexes of the triangle:

```
pts= tri(idx, :);
```

Create a matrix that represents [equation of a plane](http://www.spatialanalysisonline.com/HTML/triangulation_with_linear_inte.htm) (triangle) given its 3 points:

```
m=[X(pts);Y(pts);Z(pts);ones(1,3)].';
```

Calculate `z` based on `det(m)=0`.**

```
    z = (...
            -xi*det(m(:,2:end)) + ...
            yi*det([m(:,1) m(:,3:end)]) +...
            det(m(:,1:end-1))...
        )...
        / det([m(:,1:2) m(:,end)]);
```

*Here the Octave function `tsearch` is used that is deprecated in newer versions of MATLAB . Instead of it you can use [pointLocation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/triangulation.pointlocation.html).

**Formula for calculating determinant of a `[4 ,4]` matrix can be found in  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant).